# Getting php $_GET value in array

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to get each $_GET from url string request in an array.

So if user A visits site with [www.example.com?user="bob"](http://www.example.com?user=%22bob%22), pass to array 'users'.
Now alice visits with [www.example.com?user=alice](http://www.example.com?user=alice), pass to array 'users'.

I have tried this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php>
$Users = array();
$Member = $_GET['name'];
$Users[] = $Member;
print_r($Users);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But I still get only the last value, that is..Array( [0] => "Alice" )

Mmm, so do I need a function, to fill the array?

Thnx

Comment: Turn on error reporting. `$Member = $_GET['name']` and `$Users[] = $Member` are both missing a `;`

Comment: You need a place to store all incoming data for later usage. Either a database or a file on the server where you store all names

Comment: @brombeer, thnx, yes typo's on the ```;```, so first write fist to file? Using ```$_POST```?

Comment: You need a place to store the values. A second request to your page knows nothing about the first request. "Bob" may be stored in your array but as soon as Alice loads the page all data from the first request is gone. Store your data somewhere, preferably a database. Even if this worked with one file, everytime your file gets called, `$Users = array();` resets the array

Comment: Thnx @brombeer, I suspected something like that, but you made it clear....The data is rather ephemeral, so a database is an option, but maybe a file might be better. I'll follow up with solution as soon as I have one.

Comment: Look at functions like `serialize` or `json_encode` for converting data structures into something you can write to a file.

Comment: `$array=filter_input_array(INPUT_GET)` will store $_GET in $array with an optional filter and sanitization but not sure waht you try to accomplish here

Answer (score 0):

try with SESSION ,

```
<?php
session_start();
$Users = array();
$Member = $_GET['name'];
$_SESSION['users'][] = $Member;
print_r($_SESSION['users']);
?>
```

For more informations, you can take a look at the Session Handling https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php section of the manual, that gives some useful informations.

Answer (score 0):

PHP creates new process for every web request. Subsequent requests share no memory or other resources. Each time PHP process is created, new memory pool is initialized for this process. So it is impossible to use memory as a storage for subsequent requests.

You need some kind of permanent storage like file on disk or a database. One process can write to this storage and the other one can read from it.